# Problem with authenticating private channels in laravel with java client

Tags: java, php, laravel, pusher, laravel-passport

I want to send broadcast messages from server (using laravel) to clients (using java).

**What I'm using**

1. [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) as boradcast driver.
2. laravel passport for api authentication.

**What I've done in server side**

1. I've configured my Pusher credentials in `.env` file.
2. Uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` line in `config/app.php` file.
3. In `config/auth.php` file I've added the following:

```php
'guards' => [
     'web' => [
         'driver' => 'session',
         'provider' => 'users',
     ],

     'devices' => [
         'driver' => 'session',
         'provider' => 'devices',
     ],

     'api' => [
         'driver' => 'passport',
         'provider' => 'devices',
     ],
 ],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

     // using devices table to authenticate over api guard
    'devices' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Device::class,
    ],
],
```

4. In `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider` class I added the following to `boot()` function:

```php
Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api']);
```

5. In `routes/channels.php` I added the following:

```php
Broadcast::channel('device.{device_id}', function ($device, $device_id) {
    return $device->id === $device_id;
});
```

6. Created an event `AdvertisementAdded` by running `php artisan make:event AdvertisementAdded`, added `implements ShouldBroadcast` then added the following to its `broadcastOn()` method:

```php
return new PrivateChannel('device.'.$this->device_id);
```

**What I've done in client side**

Because I'm just testing now, I got my `access_token` and `device_id` by sending a login request from postman

[image: Getting access_token from postman]

I copied that accessToken to my java client and stored it in `accessToken` variable as `String`, here's the code:

```java
String accessToken = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImY3ZTVlMTAzZWE3MzJjMTI5NzY1YTliMmMzOTM0N2ZhOGE4OTU5MjRjNDA5ZjgyOTA4ZDg5NTFjZTBkOGZlNTA2M2M1YTI1MDBlOTdhZDdiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZjdlNWUxMDNlYTczMmMxMjk3NjVhOWIyYzM5MzQ3ZmE4YTg5NTkyNGM0MDlmODI5MDhkODk1MWNlMGQ4ZmU1MDYzYzVhMjUwMGU5N2FkN2IiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTkwOTYyNDgsIm5iZiI6MTU1OTA5NjI0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTkwNzE4NjQ3LCJzdWIiOiI3Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.FKeE9Z-wv2yUNQPl-qsbu9baYGTdbQ6DuzaI1R8azR6l1CIP9uRI4hCaoWvgx0GXWWLPRNhfQl-YD3KP2YOraW16-h4ie_95B9VQrpFxXnlqKojsfh1xSrSNSl5HncslMWQPVjoesBpM5y_cpG19PGgu-SWo0W6s9Fiz_Nm70oyyZB9mSqU8PVQvAOSNr6TMR0aC3iMLFfkyZkTSwj8EoRyD2LGW6v4PFriqx8JLbZASCOiUYBlYnunWrTFDOAenZcoa5Sw7u7kbSvYehjDKRwKjQM6zmPfi0A3Mp0CHjHE599OXb-NG2IMH-wmlT0vEZjP2U97hxmsNW1RtHNXWaRKFL9T-WVmZbJf3fH5hXqTv495L3MQfq_m5YFHyc5NuIqK4K4xMJB956a33ICnH8DmvPmJgderNAhqEX1JHUAsR63K7xbZxRBDS8OlQYcEf-_v75X0kT1s067enSvI8Vs212AVnI6k0FmgQNM8DfJUq6YduD0m2F2ZWpKPrwdd6PdW5ZlZTEv-D8dYIEQ_CwOWohNoENATmTqxDpPBxK5c723MEt8S7Sa9MEGAo56HW3-9pbazbEdY1GqPWKVkov7K_6eBFcWsV67AgJpoKFt6RiBfRvokgiH96WG89qBB_Ucpm8uBahX93FaOXhVLW0VjJH2LQKrGw0bb5LS8Ql5o";
String deviceId = "7";

Map<String, String> authHeaders = new HashMap();

authHeaders.put("Authorization", accessToken);

HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("http://localhost:8000/api/broadcasting/auth");
authorizer.setHeaders(authHeaders);
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
options.setAuthorizer(authorizer).setCluster(PUSHER_CLUSTER);
Pusher pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_APP_KEY, options);

pusher.subscribePrivate("private-device." + deviceId, new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Received event on channel [%s]", channelName));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String string) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Subscribed to channel [%s]", string));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(String string, Exception excptn) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
});

pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
        System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                           " from " + change.getPreviousState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
    }
});

// Keeping main thread alive
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When running the code above, it outputs the following on console:

```
State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED
State changed to CONNECTED from CONNECTING
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8000/api/broadcasting/auth
```

I'm sure that `auth:api` middleware is working as I expect on other requests.

Here's a snippet from my `routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('advertisements')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/request', 'AdvertisementsController@getDeviceAdvertisements')
            ->name('advertisements.getDeviceAdvertisements');
    });
});
```

And here's a test to that route from postman (with the same access token as above):

[image: Successful api authentication test on postman]

And here's a test to `api/broadcasting/auth` route from postman (with the same access token as above):

[image: Failed api authentication on api/broadcasting/auth route]

What's the problem? Why all api routes under `auth:api` middleware working properly but not `api/broadcasting/auth` route??

**Note**

I tried working with public channels with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of searching, finally It's solved.

The error happens when authorizing the channel, not when authenticating the request using `auth:api` middleware.

My private channel authorizing function in `routes/channels.php` always returns `false` meaning it will reject all subscribing requests to `private-device.{device_id}` channel:

```php
Broadcast::channel('device.{device_id}', function ($device, $device_id) {
    // this always return false, because of inequality of types
    return $device->id === $device_id;
});
```

Authorizing function above always return `false`, because of inequality of types between `$device->id` (which is of type `int`) and `$device_id` (which is of type `string`).

So, in order to solve the problem, I cast both of them to `int` and then checked for equality.

Here's the code I used to solve the problem:

```php
Broadcast::channel('device.{device_id}', function ($device, $device_id) {
    return (int) $device->id === (int) $device_id;
});
```